# I cant use labelVisibilityMode

Tags: android, dependencies, bottomnavigationview

I dont understand even i already added dependency design 
why ouccured this happen?

[image: my error]

[image: my error..]

[image: my dependency]

[image: my Source]

[image: i try to do this but something show another error]

Comment: use android:background="#ffffff" in bottomnavigationview try this

Comment: i try do that but it error still show  
error: attribute labeVisibilityMode (aka com.example.blogapp:labeVisibilityMode) not found.

Comment: use android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" instaed of labeVisibilityMode

Comment: i try do that but something another error appeared and i upload photo

Comment: now do one thing go to file--> choose Invaidate and Restart

Comment: sorry im not english speaker and still unfamiliar use this web stie I will effort more

Answer (score 6):

Try to used new material.io 2.0 and androidx..
Try this code..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<include
    android:id="@+id/amToolbar"
    layout="@layout/app_toolbar"
    />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/activity_main_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/amToolbar"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/bottom_navigation"
     />

<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_menu" />

 </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Refer this link
https://material.io/design/components/bottom-navigation.html

Comment: This way is entirely different ways

Answer (score 0):

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"/>
```

Please use this above code for the labelVisibilityMode
Also add this dependancy in app level gradle

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-alpha3'
```

Comment: It didnt working TT 
same issue appeared ... i upload photo 
error show like that it same error appeared

Comment: use the above code and try to restart the IDE. Try invalidate Caches/Restart from file or try Clean Project and Build Project from Build

Comment: unfortunately still error TT 
error: failed linking references.
but thanks... maybe i try to change the way entirely